# Happily Married

Tags: combinatorics

Let $B$ be a set of boys (possibly infinite). Each boy $b∈B$ knows a finite set of girls $G_b$. We want to marry each boy with some girl (legally: thus no girl can be married with more than one boy).

A necessary condition for this is of course that each finite subset of $n$ boys knows at least $n$ girls.

Prove that this is a sufficient condition as well!

Sorry ABOUT the Title. I didn't find any other good title.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem

Comment: How is that condition necessary? If you have equal numbers of boys and girls, then they can all be married legally, even if nobody knows anybody else.

Comment: The condition "each finite subset of $n$ boys knows at least $n$ girls" is not clear. Does a set of boys "know" a girl if they **all** know her, or if **at least one** of them knows her?

Comment: @bof: Considering the standard formalization of the case where $B$ and $\bigcup_{b\in B} G_b$ are finite - this is the perfect matching problem - I think it's reasonable to assume that "a set of boys knows a set of girls if for every girl in the set of girls, there is at least one boy in the set of boys who knows her". I think it's also reasonable to assume that two strangers won't marry.

Comment: @G.Bach I think it's reasonable to include such definitions and assumptions in the statement of the problem.